# Inverse of matrix with QR method

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity

What is the complexity of finding the inverse of matrix by QR decomposition? A is a $n×n$ with full rank.

Comment: What is the size of the input matrix? $n\times n$? Is it full rank?

Comment: Yes it is $n×n$ and full rank

Comment: The title and body seem to bear no relation to each other. I suspect that in the body "matrix" was supposed to read "the inverse of a matrix"?

Comment: Yes, you are right @joriki. I wrote it fast.

Comment: Note that I had also provided the correct articles to make the question grammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I recall, the QR decomposition stage requires $O\left(n^3\right)$ operations.

If I assume that you are not finding the inverse, but solving the linear system $Ax=b$, then once you have found the QR decomposition of $A$, the remaining operations are all $O\left(n^2\right)$.

If you are explicitly finding the inverse, then this will require an additional $O\left(n^3\right)$ operations once you have found the QR decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the $QR$ decomposition has complexity $O(n^3)$, after which $A = QR$ can be inverted into $R^{-1} Q^T$ also by $O(n^3)$ operations. In many of these algorithms, it is not the *complexity* that is important, but rather the *numerical stability*. It is well-known that first decomposing into $QR$ before inverting provides greater stability.

Comment: This. More or less all *dense* linear algebra is in $O(n^3)$ field operations, unless you decide to use a funkier matrix multiplication exponent, i.e. Coppsmith-Winograd's.